# How to use ember data with nested hasMany relationships?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have some data models that look like this:

```
App.Order = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  legs: DS.hasMany('leg', {async: false})
});


App.Leg = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  order: DS.belongsTo('order'),
  stops: DS.hasMany('stop', {async: false})
});


App.Stop = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  leg: DS.belongsTo('leg'),
});
```

The returned JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Order 1",
      "legs": []
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Order 2",
      "legs": [1]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Order 3",
      "legs": [2,3]
    }
  ],
  "legs": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Leg 1",
      "stops": [1,2]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Leg 2",
      "stops": [2,3]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Leg 3",
      "stops": [1,3]
    }
  ],
  "stops": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Stop 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Stop 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Stop 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I was using `async:true`, ember made http requests for the related legs (`legs?ids[]=1` and `legs?ids[]=2&ids[]=3`) but would never make a request for the related stops.

So I switched to sideloading as shown above, but the stops are still NOT available from the related legs.

Can you help me understand how the loading of Models with nested hasMany relationships SHOULD be done? Or where I've gone wrong? I'm open to using either `async: true` or `async: false`, as long as I can get the nested data loaded in to the model.

Comment: This example with sideloaded-data should work, check this example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuhag/1/edit

Comment: And so it does. Thanks. Your example clued me in that the problem was in my template, not in the data. Sigh. Thank you!